# What is the differences between updateOrCreate() and updateOrInsert() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Both methods seem to create a new record if not existed or update a record with provided data. Whats the difference between the two?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`updateOrCreate` is method of [Eloquent Builder](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_updateOrCreate) and `updateOrInsert` is method of [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_updateOrInsert).

`updateOrCreate` returns model, whereas `updateOrInsert` returns boolean

---

Signatures from Laravel code:

**updateOrCreate**

```
/**
 * Create or update a record matching the attributes, and fill it with values.
 *
 * @param  array  $attributes
 * @param  array  $values
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|static
 */
public function updateOrCreate(array $attributes, array $values = [])
```

**updateOrInsert**

```
/**
 * Insert or update a record matching the attributes, and fill it with values.
 *
 * @param  array  $attributes
 * @param  array  $values
 * @return bool
 */
public function updateOrInsert(array $attributes, array $values = [])
```